# No such process - ptrace

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, ptrace

**Problem statement**: a program **C** is composed of a loop. The execution of this program must be controlled by another process that will periodically display the progress of the controlled process. After `kill(pid, SIGSTOP),` the function `ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT,pid,...)` does not find anymore the **C** process. From what I have read, `ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT,pid,...`) is supposed to work when the process identified by `pid` is stopped.

I do not know what exactly I am missing, so any help will be much appreciated. Below is what I have done so far:

There are two processes, **P** and **C**.

The first process (P) creates the second one (C) via ***fork()*** .

C's code is like this:

```
int i = 0;
int main() {
     ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
     printf("Memory address = %p", (void *)&i);
     while(1) { i++;}
}
```

P's code is below:

```
{...}
switch (pid = fork()) {
case 0: /* the child */           
       if (execl("C", "", (char *) NULL) == -1)  {
        perror("execl");
    }
    break;

case -1: /* Error */
    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

default: /* the parent */  
        sleep(1);
        kill(pid, SIGSTOP);
        wait(&status);            
        if (WSTOPSIG(status)==SIGSTOP) {
                printf("%s","Child was interrupted. Insert memory address\n");

            scanf("%p",&address);
            printf("Address = %p", address);               

            data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, pid, address,NULL);        
            if(data==-1){
               if(errno){
                printf("%s\n","Error at PEEKTEXT\n");    
                printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));    
               }
               if(errno ==     ESRCH){
                printf("%s\n","ESRCH error\n");    
               }
                if(errno == EIO){
                printf("%s\n","EIO error\n");    
               }
            }
            printf("***Data retrieved is: %ld\n",data);
            data = ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0);

        }    
        if(WIFEXITED(status)){
            printf("[Parent] - Child's exit status is: %d \n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
            break;
        }
    break;        
} 
{...}
```

The output is:

1. From C: Memory Address = 0x60104c
2. From P: Child was interrupted. Insert memory address (next I insert what C printed)

Address = 0x60104c

And the **error** is:

Error at PEEKTEXT

No such process

ESRCH ERROR

***DATA retrieved is: -1

Comment: Works for me. I added necessary includes and defined all the variables, compiled both P and C and it worked. Can you post the complete code which can be compiled? Any chance you have an error somewhere in `...`, e.g. incorrect type for some variable, etc.?  Also, try running `strace -f -o strace.log ./p` and check what is printed in `strace.log`.

Comment: You were right, the issue was in `...` as @roxana_roman mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the address variable is of the correct type. I tried with `void * address`  and it worked for me also. I got your error by using `int` for address variable

Comment: That was have been the issue. I was using `unsigned int` :). Thanks!

Comment: Thought about this possibility but was not sure — cool that you guessed correctly. Will add a bit to your answer: the size of address (for `%p`) is 8 bytes on x86_64 so when `scanf` tried to read a value into `unsigned int` (instead of `int *`) it just put garbage to some other value in the memory, and in your case it was the `pid` variable — hence the error. It could be some other variable if they were allocated differently, or it could even work without any error. If the author printed the value of `pid` before calling `ptrace` he would have seen some garbage and would have found an error.

Answer (score 2):

Use `waitpid` with the following options:

```
waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED)
```